# What to use in stead of UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is deprecated starting iOS 11. The docs say to use PHPickerViewController, but that is only available starting iOS 14. What should I use for projects that fall in between, i.e. that a project that requires iOS 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset instead of UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL. This is available from iOS 11

[image]